# FCC api project. I do not understand the flow of the code with promises

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, promise

I'm stuck on some code and I do not understand why. I'm determined not to copy and paste but to understand what Im doing (and doing wrong).
The problem is where I want to make the new Url object in the post route. It makes the the object but does not wait for the function getHighestShort to resolve its promise and always returns shortMax as 1.
If I console log on some code lines, I can see that the code in the if statement in the getHighestShort function is resolved after making and saving the Url object and therefore the Url object will always have short_url as 1.
I would really appreciate some hints in the right direction, because I thought the await before the new Url would make that line of code hold up the rest of the code.
-42 year old self learner- So this post might sound a bit all over the place :)

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Url = require('./schemas/urlModel');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/urlshortener', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log('connection open'))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))

const app = express();

// Basic Configuration
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.use(cors());

app.use('/public', express.static(`${process.cwd()}/public`));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/views/index.html');
});

// Your first API endpoint
//find input url in db and return the long version
app.get('/api/shorturl/:input', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {input} = req.params
    // const shortUrlNr = parseInt(input)
    console.log(input)
    console.log(Url.findOne( {short_url: `${input}`} ))
    const found = await Url.findOne( {short_url: `${input}`} )
    res.redirect(`https://${found.full_url}`)
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      console.log(res.status)
  }
})

app.post('/api/shorturl/new', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { url } = await req.body
    //check for valid url, if not respond with json object as asked in tests.
    if (!validURL(url)) {
      return res.json({error: 'invalid url'})
    } else {
      //find url in db and get json response with the corresponding object. 
      //If it is already in the db, than redirect to this website as asked in tests. 
        const foundUrl = await Url.findOne( {full_url: `${url}`} )
        if (foundUrl !== null) {
          res.redirect(`https://${foundUrl.full_url}`)
        } else {
        //if the url is not there, we''ll create a new entry with that url.
        const newUrl = await new Url( {full_url: `${url}`,  short_url: `${getHighestShort()}`} )
        await newUrl.save()
        res.json(newUrl)
        } 
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('catch error post request')
    return next(err)
  }
})

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});

function validURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
  return !!pattern.test(str);
}

function getHighestShort() {
  let shortMax = 1
  //make an array from the collection with short values sorted descending
  //and than pick the first one which should be the highest value.
  //if the array is empty just return 1 as it is the first one
  Url.find({}).sort({short_url: 1}).exec()
    .then(res => {
      if (res.length !== 0) {
        shortMax = res[0].short_url + 1
      } 
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('catch err server.js function getHighestShort')
      console.log(err)
    })
    return shortMax
}
```

model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const urlSchema = new Schema( 
    {
        full_url: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        short_url: Number
    }
)

const Url = mongoose.model('Url', urlSchema)

module.exports = Url
```

Answer (score 0):

The [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operators waits on a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), for it to work like you expect you need it to be used on one.

For example in the line:

```
const { url } = await req.body
```

`await` is pointless here because `req.body` is not a promise, it's an object. so it will be the same as doing:

```
const { url } = req.body
```

Now why isn't your code working? Let's start by understanding `getHighestShort`, does it return a promise? ( spoiler alert it doesn't ).

So first we need to make it return a promise ( and then we will have to wait for that promise to resolve ).

Step 1, make `getHighestShort` return a promise:

```
function getHighestShort() {
    let shortMax = 1
    //make an array from the collection with short values sorted descending
    //and than pick the first one which should be the highest value.
    //if the array is empty just return 1 as it is the first one
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Url.find({}).sort({short_url: 1}).exec()
            .then(res => {
                if (res.length !== 0) {
                    shortMax = res[0].short_url + 1;
                }
                resolve(shortMax)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('catch err server.js function getHighestShort')
                console.log(err)
                // you decide logic here
                resolve(shortMax)
            })
    })
}
```

Now I personally recommend you re-write this a little to make it a bit cleaner, something like so:

```
async function getHighestShort() {
    let shortMax = 1
    try {
        //make an array from the collection with short values sorted descending
        //and than pick the first one which should be the highest value.
        //if the array is empty just return 1 as it is the first one
        const results = await Url.find({}).sort({short_url: 1}).limit(1).exec()
        if (res.length !== 0) {
            shortMax = res[0].short_url + 1
        }
        return shortMax
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('catch err server.js function getHighestShort')
        console.log(err)
        return shortMax
    }
}
```

Notice I added `limit(1)`, there is no need to read the entire collection on each call.

I want to add that you have some wrong assumptions here about the atomicity of the operations, what happens if 2 requests are processed at the same time? you will have 2 urls with the same `short_url`.

I will leave this problem for you to handle on your own.

Step 2, now that `getHighestShort` returns a promise. we need to wait on it:

```
const short_url = await getHighestShort();
const newUrl = await new Url( {full_url: `${url}`,  short_url: short_url} )
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to explain things!